# TFS 2017 Query Related Items In Build upon release

Tags: tfs, build

I've received a request to create a custom report email for our executives. When we do a major release they want a list of Features of that release. What i need to do is read the related Tasks to the release then traverse up parent nodes until i get to the features that are marked with a tag "Executive". My Issue is that I can't find any document on how get the "Work items linked to associated changes".
I've been able to just through to get the specific build
GET http://XXX.MYTFSSERVER.COM/tfs/Collection/Project/e5e632e2-ae70-41c9-9d72-6686d2375f14/_apis/build/Builds/69330

But I don't see any link to get the workitems associated to the build.

Answer (score 1):

Releases already do this out-of-the-box. On the *Work Items* tab of a release, you can have it generate an email that contains all of the work items associated with that release relative to an earlier release.

Comment: I know that feature exists but it's not what I need

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any build-in way to achieve this such as through TFS work item query. You need to build a extension to get all work items of specific release and filter them later.

> The steps to achieve that with extension:
>
> 1. Get specify release to get build id
> 2. Get work items of that build per build id
> 3. Get related work items
> 4. Filter the work items which you actually need

A detail simple code of extension to get work items of specific release that you can refer to this link: [TFS 2017 Release Management: How to display parent PBI for Tasks under Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934425/tfs-2017-release-management-how-to-display-parent-pbi-for-tasks-under-release)